# Projected band structure plot - orbital characteristics plotted vs the K values?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, electronic-band-theory, density-functional-theory

I'm not understanding what is it that I have to plot for obtaining the orbital characteristics of a band in the band structure diagram. Usually we plot the energy eigenvalues for a given k point.

Now suppose I get the orbital characteristics through some DFT calculation which shows the Kpoints vs the orbital contribution in fractions (say S orbital contribution is 0.44, P is 0 and so on for all values of K). For all the bands in the system how do I plot this data? Do I multiply the corresponding energy eigenvalues with the contribution and plot it vs K?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The first question to ask yourself is: what are you trying to convey with the plot? Is such a plot actually useful to somebody else? So, clarify to yourself what point you want to get across with a figure, and focus on that.

Comment: Hi, I would like to know which orbitals contribute to which energy levels..

Comment: I might suggest looking at relevant papers and seeing how they have done it. I have seen various ways. Although, I would also say that in general I really don't care all that much - the important point to me ultimately is the resulting band structure, not where it came from (mainly because where it came from doesn't impact anything in particular).

Comment: 4 years is long to not get an answer, you can copy and paste here: https://materials.stackexchange.com now that Materials.SE is live.